# Django URL regular expressions for random string as ID

Tags: python, regex, django

I need to allow ID's in my URL that match

`[int]_` followed by random string of length 22 can be letter or number but never has URL unsafe strings such as `/` or `+` or `=` etc. for example an id looks like this:

i.e.

- 4_h-rbVeqURNqc-nPSj5ojfA
- 10_81hjsqURNqc-nPPLkaiZ1

This is what Django Docs has for standard id matching...

```
url(r'^article/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/?$', views.detail.as_view(), name='article'),
```

How do I match/validate my type of IDs with a regular expressions for above?

I have tried `[\w|\W]+` etc, but this does not validate nor match my usecase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following regex :

```
\d+_([\w-]+){22}
```

`\w` will match any word character contain alphabetical characters and letters and character `_`.So `[\w-]+` will match any combinations of `\w` and `-` with length 1 or more.

Comment: To be precise, `\w` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so you need the extra `-`, but not an extra `_`.